# Possible to override bash environment variable completion?

Tags: bash, tab-completion, bash-completion, fzf

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `complete` bash builtin to override tab completion of "environment variables." That is, when there is a **dollar sign** `$` to the left of the cursor, with all characters between the dollar sign and the cursor `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Is this possible?

Specifically, I'm hoping to enable [FZF fuzzy completion](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) of environment variables.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: try `shopt -s direxpand`